# Remove Sublime Text 3 completely

Tags: 14.04, uninstall, sublime-text

I want to remove completely Sublime Text 3 from my system. I have tried this:

```
sudo apt-get purge sublime-text-installer
```

and the application is gone, but when I install it again...

```
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

...the themes and the plugins remain installed.

Comment: **This works:**

`sudo apt-get remove --purge sublime-text`

Of course you may have some other package different from sublime-text depending on which package you installed to begin with. You just need to make sure you know WHAT that that original package name is, of course, to remove it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found my own solution. The configuration packages and other data where under `$HOME/.config/sublime-text-3`. Once I removed that folder, all was golden.

Answer (score 3):

The full answer is the combination of both the methods.

This folder really contains all the Sublime text 3 settings for the current user:

```
$HOME/.config/sublime-text-3
```

Folders structure may be like this:

```
Backup
Cache
Index
Installed Packages
Local
Packages
```

But to remove it completely you will need to call:

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove sublime-text-installer
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove sublime-text-installer
```

Then to install again you would call

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/sublime-text-3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sublime-text-installer
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked successfully for me:

First, I removed the *sublime text* package and any other dependant packages which are no longer needed from my Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove sublime-text-installer
```

Then I deleted the  configuration and data files of *sublime text* and it's dependencies from Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove sublime-text-installer
```

This is the main output of the last command which I believe interests you more:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 369782 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing sublime-text-installer (3114-2~webupd8~0) ...
Purging configuration files for sublime-text-installer (3114-2~webupd8~0) ...
```